# Select set of occupy rows from given value using Sql server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like

```
ID | Values
1  |  10
2  |  20
3  |  30
4  |  40
5  |  20
6  |  5
7  |  3

and declare @given_value int=100;
```

If given value is 35,then the result is first 2 rows because 10+20<=35 condition.
If given value is 100,then the result is first 4 rows because 10+20+30+40<=100 condition.

> That means i want to get occupy able  rows based on given values.And i
>   tried cumulative sum using self join but it should use aggregate
>   function.so please give another ideas or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

```
select * from Yourtable A
Cross Apply
(
select sum(B.[Values]) as Run_Tot from Yourtable B
Where A.ID >= B.ID
) cs
Where Run_Tot <= 30 -- @given_value
```

- **[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/KBA44538)**

It can be done much easier and faster in `Sql Server 2012+` versions

```
select * from 
(
select *,sum(B.[Values]) Over(Order by ID) as Run_Tot 
from Yourtable B
) a
Where Run_Tot <= 30 -- @given_value
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a variation on the classic "Bin Packing" problem... (You have bins of some size and you must figure out the the optimal combination of items to go into each bin to pack all items with the fewest bins.)

This is actually quite a bit simpler but still requires looping (or in this case recursion)

The code below, will find you all possible combinations of items that total to the size of the bin...

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [Value] INT NOT NULL
    );

INSERT #TestData(ID, Value) VALUES
    (1, 10),
    (2, 20),
    (3, 30),
    (4, 40),
    (5, 20),
    (6, 5),
    (7, 3);

--SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

--===========================

DECLARE @BinVal INT = 95;

WITH
    cte_Recursion AS (
        SELECT 
            td.ID,
            td.Value,
            ID_String = CAST(CONCAT(',', td.ID) AS VARCHAR(8000))
        FROM 
            #TestData td
        WHERE
            td.Value <= @BinVal
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            td.ID,
            Value = td.Value + r.Value,
            ID_String = CAST(CONCAT(',', td.ID, r.ID_String) AS VARCHAR(8000))
        FROM 
            cte_Recursion r
            JOIN #TestData td
                ON r.ID < td.ID
        WHERE
            td.value + r.Value <= @BinVal
        )
SELECT  
    ID_String = STUFF(r.ID_String, 1, 1, ''),
    BinVakue = r.Value
FROM 
    cte_Recursion r
WHERE
    r.Value = @BinVal
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```